# view offset by Custom navigationBar setBackgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, offset

I set Custom navigationBar by KVO in iOS8,and the custom navigationBar setBackgroundImage.

I found that the `viewContoller.view.frame.origin.y` is 64 and viewController is Navigation's rootViewController.

why `viewContoller.view.frame.origin.y` is 64 in iOS 8?

the following is demo code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *temp = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
    [temp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController setValue:temp forKey:@"navigationBar"];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSLog(@"view : %@",self.view); // print :<UIView: 0x7ff8fa72cfa0; frame = (0 64; 375 603); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff8fa72b2b0>>
}
```

If I cancel `[temp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` , the `view.origin.y` is `0` correctly.

what i should do correctly to set custom `navigationBar` which setBackgroundImage and keep `self.view.orgin` is `(0,0)`?

Comment: @ViralSavaj  the navigationBar Property of NavigationController is readonly. (@property(nonatomic,readonly) UINavigationBar *navigationBar),we can't  self.navigationController.navigationBar = customNavigatioBar;

Comment: your viewController's frame **IS** going to change if UINavigationBar has a height(of 64). Work with `view.bounds` instead

Comment: @JingLiangWen, you can check answer for getting your self.view.orgin to (0,0).

Comment: @ViralSavaj it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please check the image assets.

The image "navbar_bg@2x" should exists in the assets, If you are tested on device or simulators ,which has UIKit Scale factor 2.0, such as a iPhone 8 .

The image "navbar_bg@3x" should exists in the assets, if tested on iPhone 8 Plus. And so on.

It should be OK, according to Apple's Demo Code [Customizing Your App’s Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar).

---

Two cases , your issue happens.

- In my case , It does not work, when converting color to image.

Firstly I thought it is image size issue.

Accoring to Debug View Hierarchy, I got the BackgroundImageView's size, 414 X 88.Tested in simulator of iPhone XR.

[image: One]

When debugging, I think maybe the image should be smaller than imageView'size.
Still not work, after many times of adjusting the image size.

the code of converting color to image:

```
public static func color(_ color: UIColor, width w: CGFloat, height h: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: w, height: h)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        ctx?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        ctx?.fill(rect)
        var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        return image
    }
```

- case two: image@2x ("navbar_bg@2x") doesn't exist in assets when tested in simulator of iPhone XR, which has UIKit Scale factor 2.0.

Then it doesn't work either in my experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can set title of `navigationController.navigationItem` instead of setting up `UINavigationBar` and providing with KVO.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg"]];
    //Here you can create your own Custom View and provide as title of self.navigationController.navigationItem
    [self.navigationController.navigationItem setTitleView:img];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSLog(@"view : %@",self.view); // print :<UIView: 0x79ea0a30; frame = (0 0; 375 603); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x79ea0ac0>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an experiment too.

I think the problem is caused by color space.

According to the answer above, I created three images of white with imageMagick.

And use white image@2x with  simulator iPhone XR .

The issue happens too.

The example image of Apple's Demo Code [Customizing Your App’s Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar) is of SRBG, my color image is simply gray scale.

I think it is the difference.

[image]

[from image magick community](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17207)

> -colorspace changes the way the image is stored in memory
>   -set colorspace just sets the colorsapce of the image without conversion
>
> Many image formats (like JPG) do not use difference colorspaces
>   without using some time of color profile, as such the image is
>   converted back to RGB colorspace unless a color profile has been
>   defined.
>
> That is why you don't see a difference. It is only different IN
>   MEMORY!

Maybe iOS did some optimization because of this.